# Removing identical variables in CFG Unit Productions

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Productions of the form A-> A are removed immediately, but what if the production is of the form A -> AA?

example: 
A -> AA | a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you example the production `A->AA` can not be removed. If that production is removed then the language described by the grammar will change. But in case of a production like `A->A`, the removal will not affect the language described by the Grammar.